# Only approved documents should be shown

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I tried this stored procedure to show documents:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[financespmanager] 
     @DepID int
as
    SELECT     
        dbo.DocumentInfo.DocID as DocumentID, 
        dbo.DocumentInfo.DocName as DocumentName, 
        dbo.DocumentInfo.Uploadfile as FileUploaded, 
        dbo.Department.DepType as Department, 
        dbo.DocType.DocType as Document,
        dbo.DocumentInfo.UploadedBy as UploadedBy, 
        dbo.Approval.AppoveBy, 
        dbo.ApproveType.ApproveType as Status
    FROM         
        dbo.DocumentInfo 
    INNER JOIN
        dbo.Approval ON dbo.DocumentInfo.DocID = dbo.Approval.DocID
    INNER JOIN
        dbo.ApproveType ON dbo.Approval.ApproveID = dbo.ApproveType.ApproveID 
    INNER JOIN
        dbo.Department ON dbo.DocumentInfo.DepID = dbo.Department.DepID
    INNER JOIN
        dbo.DocType ON dbo.DocumentInfo.DocTypeID = dbo.DocType.DocTypeID
    WHERE     
        DocumentInfo.DepID = @DepID
```

Now when I test query it show me like this

```
DocumentID  DocumentName  FileUploaded    Departmen   UploadedBy   AppoveBy    Status
 25       css           dsfsdf.docx     Computer    edward       halten      Rejected
 18       hr            HR.docx         Computer    john         halten      Approved
 19       eco           eco 2.docx      Computer    kety         halten      Rejected
 24       plan          December8.pdf   Computer    edward       halten      Approved
```

Now here I want to show only approved documents not reject and pending documents

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need an additional condition in your `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE     
    DocumentInfo.DepID = @DepID 
    AND dbo.ApproveType.ApproveType = 'Approved'
```

That should do it.

Comment: when i try your query it shows me errro "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Approve' to data type int"

Comment: @user2931015: see my update - you probably have an actual column called `Status` of type `int` - and you also use `Status` as the column alias on that `dbo.ApproveType.ApproveType` column - that's rather confusing, I'd say ....

Comment: when i use this like this AND Status = 'Approve' then it shows me error Ambiguous column name 'Status'.and when i use like this ApproveType.ApproveID='Approve' then it shows me error Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Approve' to data type int

Comment: @user2931015, That's exactly what I had in my answer!

Comment: yup i know @christiandev ;)

Answer (score 1):

try...

`AND ApproveType.ApproveType = 'Approved'` in there `where` clause.

or, alter the stored procedure to take a **second param**...

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[financespmanager] 
     @DepID int,
     @Status varchar(30) = 'Approved'
as
--rest of sp
WHERE 
DocumentInfo.DepID = @DepID 
AND ApproveType.ApproveType = @Status
```

The default will be `Approved`, but you could also pass in another value to override...

```
EXEC [dbo].[financespmanager] @DepID = n, @Status = 'Rejected'
```

This will allow you to use the SP "as-is", but also give the flexibility to override.

Comment: @user2931015, Did you not see my answer when using `status` was not working for you?

Comment: @user2931015, the point I am making is that I had already answered with the correct version, yet you **accepted** the other answer after it was edited to match mine...anyway, you accept whatever!